# How to automatically update a Team Fortress 2 server with SteamCMD?

Tags: team-fortress-2, hosting, windows, steamcmd

I have a Windows server running Team Fortress 2 (TF2) with SteamCMD and I would like to enable auto-updates.

For the moment, I have to do it manually with SteamCMD using the `app_update` command but this is very bad as I must check daily if there are new updates.

This is what I've tried :

- The `-autoupdate` arg when I launch the game (`srcds.exe -autoupdate ...`)
- Putting the SteamCMD commands in a text file and using the `-steam_dir` and `-steam_script` args

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: `-autoupdate`, along with `-steam_dir` and `-steamcmd_script` which tell autoupdate where to find things, only work on Linux.  This is because Windows won't let the game server overwrite DLL files that are currently loaded into memory... including server.dll, which is the main server code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to 'push' updates to your server, only regular pulls.

First up: create a batch file to update in one click.

```
@echo off
start c:\steamcmd\steamcmd +login anonymous +force_install_dir c:\tf2server +app_update 232250 validate +quit
```

Replace relevant directories with where they appear in your system.

Next: do nightly restarts.
There are plugins out there that will stop your server at a specific time of day.
Create a operating system level scheduled task to run your update batch and then start the server again.

This is what I have implemented in my professional TF2 server; this is advice from an expert.